# Unable to upload golang app into google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am unable to upload my code into my app on Google App engine. I developed it in Golang. The code is working fine on local system but when I am trying to upload it at google app engine, it is throwing following error. Kindly help.

```
9:44 PM Getting current resource limits.
09:44 PM Scanning files on local disk.
09:45 PM Cloning 205 application files.
09:45 PM Uploading 2 files and blobs.
09:45 PM Uploaded 2 files and blobs.
09:45 PM Compilation starting.
09:45 PM Compilation: 178 files left.
09:45 PM Error 422: --- begin server output ---
Compile failed:
2016/07/14 21:45:04 go-app-builder: build timing: 26×compile (6.651s total), 0×link (0 total)
2016/07/14 21:45:04 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 1

golang.org/x/net/http2/server.go:156: undefined: isBadCipher
golang.org/x/net/http2/server.go:320: undefined: isBadCipher
golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:122: undefined: configureTransport
golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:407: undefined: transportExpectContinueTimeout
--- end server output ---
09:45 PM Rolling back the update.
Error 422: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
error while running appcfg.py: exit status 1
```

Comment: What version of Go App Engine SDK are you using? You can find out by running `goapp version`.

Comment: I am using go version go1.6 (appengine-1.9.35) linux/amd64

Comment: Are you explicitly importing the `golang.org/x/net/http2` package? Is your app in your Go workspace (`GOPATH` env variable)? Is the `http2` package downloaded in your `GOPATH` or next to your app? Newest version is `go version go1.6.1 (appengine-1.9.38) windows/amd64`. Do you experience the same error with that?

Comment: Hi ICZA - thanks for your quick response. No I am not explicitly importing http2 ..I am importing "net/http". Yes my workspace is in my GOPATH.        echo $GOPATH 
   /home/ds/work and my code is "/work/src/dheeraj/02_Basic_Structure$".  I didnt try on windows. However, until last month I was able to upload the code without any problem.

Comment: And have you tried it with the newest SDK version 1.9.38?

Comment: ha ha .. why didn't I thought of that.. Thanks  icza... It worked. I was not expecting such minor updates have such a huge impacts ..Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. Updating to the latest SDK (now 1.9.40) solved it.